# Prestashop GA4 integration

Tags: google-analytics, prestashop

I have question regarding integration Google Analytics 4 into Prestashop. My company has setup some years ago Universal Analytics. Now that Google forces everyone to slowly migrate to Google Analytics 4 I was tasked to do it.

I have created GA4 property, inserted gtag into site's code and connected it to the existing UA tag on the site. Everything is working fine, user's data is here except for revenue. Do I need to manually add everywhere custom events as in this documentation? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtag

I know that they are Prestashop modules for this but they are paid and because of this aren't a option. Also current Google Analytics module don't support GA4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the url you posted describes ecommerce implementation through gtag. If that's what you're doing, then yes, to get revenue, products, transactions and the rest of EEC-related data, you'll have to implement it as described there.

Most of people choose to implement GA4 through GTM since it's much easier to manage and maintain there. But if the intention is to have tracking with the front-end team, then direct use of gtag may be justified.

Comment: I'm not particularly attached to gtag I can do it via GTM, but do you happen to know if GTM will automatically get revenue from Presta or must I code it manually like in gtag?

Comment: you should check if presta populates dataLayer object with e-commerce objects. I believe there should be extensions for it that do that more or less. And then there are templates for GTM to make GA UA payloads to be parsed into GA4-friendly format.